# 19.10 5ghz speed slow compared to dual boot windows

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 19.10, firmware

I am running dual boot ubuntu 19.10 and windows 10 pro. When I'm connected to my home internet(500mbits up and down) via 5ghz, I am getting the following results:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Breedband Arnhem (Arnhem) [65.00 km]: 8.151 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 24.00 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 19.42 Mbit/s
```

When running windows, I can easily hit the 200+ mbits up and down on the same network.

The installed wireless adapter is the Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 with which I believe are the latest drivers and the latest firmware.

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 78
       serial: 00:28:f8:a7:f4:4a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.1-050401-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.178.88 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:dd300000-dd301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:44:d2:5d:50
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Within the Software and Updates panel I see it showing up but it says "This device is not working". [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yLnp.png) That might be part of the problem but i'm not sure as i've seen other people on here having no troubles but where it also says "This device is not working".

As asked in a comment, here the output of iwconfig

```
wlp59s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Eichhorn 5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 44:4E:6D:F9:AF:EC   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:197   Missed beacon:0
```

Below is the output for the wireless info script per request of a comment. Its an external link as the output was too long to put in here

[wireless info output](https://paste.ofcode.org/mBrn9efzBAH6efkLMEQZRn)

I've tried several things like updating my kernel, updating the adapter firmware and turning 802.11n off with modprobe. Unfortunately non of it seems to work.

I'm quite new to ubuntu and linux in general so I'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu. It is always preferred to post the text output from a terminal instead of taking a screenshot of terminal.

Comment: What does **iwconfig** show? Add to your question, please.

Comment: Run the `wireless-info` script from https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info

Comment: @waltinator I have added the output from the script to the post

Comment: @ajgringo619 I have added the iwconfig output to the post

Comment: Your link to `wireless info output` is broken.

Comment: @waltinator I believe that's now fixed